# Using Delete Button from Gridview to delete a record from Database and from Folder

Tags: asp.net

When I click on delete, the record containing the Image is removed from the database but the Image still remains in the folder. Please could any experienced asp.net programmer help?
Thank you in advance!

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Management.aspx.cs" Inherits="pages_Management_Management" %>
```

Add New Product

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID,Image" DataSourceID="generalProducts" Width="80%" OnRowEditing="grdProducts_RowEditing" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CatID" HeaderText="CatID" SortExpression="CatID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Image" HeaderText="Image" SortExpression="Image" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Seller" HeaderText="Seller" SortExpression="Seller" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StateID" HeaderText="StateID" SortExpression="StateID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CityID" HeaderText="CityID" SortExpression="CityID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StreetID" HeaderText="StreetID" SortExpression="StreetID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StreetNoID" HeaderText="StreetNoID" SortExpression="StreetNoID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Packaging" HeaderText="Packaging" SortExpression="Packaging" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit" HeaderText="Unit" SortExpression="Unit" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Product] ([Name]) VALUES (@Name)" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Product]" 
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Product] SET [Name] = @Name WHERE [ID] = @ID">

```
 <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="button" PostBackUrl="~/pages/Management/ManageProductCats.aspx">Add New ProductCat</asp:LinkButton>
</p>
<asp:GridView ID="grdProductsType" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="generalProductCat" Width="50%" style="margin-top: 0px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="generalProductCat" runat="server" ConnectionString=
    "<%$ ConnectionStrings:SuperStoreDBConnectionString %>"
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ProductCat] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ProductCat] ([Name]) VALUES (@Name)"
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ProductCat]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [ProductCat] SET [Name] = @Name WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: @MMoore94, I appreciate your contribution, the onDelete event thrown an error. Also there are many images in the DB and the Id points to the specific image to be deleted. What do you think is wrong with my method below: protected void grdProducts_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) { GridViewRow row = grdProducts.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]; int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text); File.Delete("~/Images/Products/" + rowId); }

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're using that `<asp:SqlDataSource >` as the data source for your gridview. Your SQL commands are in place and obviously your delete command works because you say it deletes it from the DB.

I don't see any code, so I assume there isn't any. You would need to add code in the "RowDeleting" event of your GridView. Code can be added there to access the filesystem and delete the file from whatever folder you're talking about.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion Peyote, I got a better understanding of the problem. However my "RowDeleting" event is throwing up an error that" No overload for 'grdProducts_RowDeleting' matches delegate'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventHandler' C:\Use..." Below is my code behind event.

Comment: protected void grdProducts_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)

    {
        // storing value from cell
        GridViewRow row2 = grdProducts.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

        // full path required
        string fileName = ("~/Images/Products/" + row2);

        if (fileName != null || fileName != string.Empty)
        {
            if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            }

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add on row deleting to your gridview tag as well as create a method in the c# for deleting the files

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="true">
```

C#

```
protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    File.Delete("put your directory path here");
}
```